# Undefined offset when using explode() for text files

Tags: php, arrays, warnings, offset, explode

I am planning to extract the contents from a text file named `itest.txt` that consists of 100 000 numbers, one number on each line.

I printed the content of `$contents` which happens to be of type `string` so all the numbers are separated by a space.

After using `explode()` I assumed that the `$ints` will contain one number per index but that is not the case. I am trying to have one number per index i.e `$ints[0]` = the first number and so on. Later I wish to convert them to integers but i can't seem to get past the string array problem. As a result I am getting the Undefined offset error.

Please do get back to me if my question wasn't clear and I am a little apprehensive about the code in the for loop, doesn't look very professional.

Here is my code:

```
$filename = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\coInv\itest.txt';
$fd       = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($fd, filesize($filename));    
$ints     = explode(" ", $contents);    
echo $ints[0];  // displays all the elements of the string.


for( $i=0 ; $i<100000 ; )
{
    $ints[$i] = int($ints[$i]);
    echo $ints[$i++];
}
```

Comment: What is your question? And which part of the error message do you not understand in specific? And why don't you use the [`file`](http://php.net/file) function like: `$ints = array_map('intval', file($filename));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to explode by line break, not space, to match your input:

```
$ints = explode("\n",$contents);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're getting just a single array element that contains the entire file, that means your `" "` in the explode() call is wrong - there are no spaces in there for explode to work on. You say it's "one person", so I'd suggest using `"\n"` are the explode parameter. However, that depends on exactly what kind of text file this is: windows, mac, unix. You may have to play with it a bit.

However, since you're just loading the file, you COULD just skip the entire fopen/fread business, and do:

```
$lines = file('ivtest.txt');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
   echo $line;
}
```

[file()](http://php.net/file) loads a file and splits the lines into an array for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To get all integer values from your file (one integer per line) into an array you should use the [`file`](http://php.net/file) function and then map each line to [it's integer value](http://php.net/intval):

```
$filename = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\coInv\itest.txt';
$ints = array_map('intval', file($filename));
```